# What causes pdfTeX warning (ext4) and how can I avoid it?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

I have a bunch of warnings as follows:

```
l.3387 \end{align}
                  pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (
name{equation.0.24}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.3392 \end{align}
```

However, I haven't duplicated naming any equations or figures.

Then it is finished off with:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

Again, there are no `??` in the document and nothing was labeled with the same name.

What can cause this, and how can it be avoided?

I have equations and figures labeled that aren't referenced since I didn't know if I would reference it so I labeled it any ways.  Is that an issue?

Just to verify, I am not using `equation` or `eqnarray` environments.

[image]

Here is possibly the important stuff from the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
```

I label the items as `\label{somenameIcreate}`.  If it is a figure, I name it after the `.tex` file that created the standalone graphic.  So if I created a graphic in a tex file called `ellipticaltrajmars.tex`, its label would be `\label{ellipticaltrajmars}`.

Would `.aux` file have anything useful in it? I know it has labels, but what would I be looking for in it if there was something to gleam from it?

Comment: That warning comes from `hyperref`. Try adding `\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}` before that section (fingers crossed because I don't know the context)

Comment: @percusse so I put that in front of every `section`, `subsection`, and `subsubsection`.  There are fewer of them now but still quite a bit.

Comment: @Markus I wish I could.  I have tried and don't know what I need to do make a MWE.

Comment: Just remove stuff in your input file until you isolate the warning. This may be time-consuming, but it's necessary. Without an MWE, any accurate diagnosis is impossible.

Comment: As a random guess (lacking an MWE), document classes with e.g. roman page numbering for front matters (Intro, declaration, ToC) and main matter (the text itself) can cause this issue, see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=pdfpagelabels

Comment: I have a possible cause and solution for your problem, but I would like to discuss it first with you. Are you available right now?

Comment: @dustin now it's me who needs a little wait. Can we meet again here in one and a half hour?

Comment: @dustin OK. Then in 90 minutes I'll write here another message letting you know that I'm available.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9916/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-dustin)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some experiments, I figured out the cause of the problem; the following MWE allows to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\ref{equ:testa}~\ref{equ:testb}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a=b\label{equ:testa}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\section{Another test section}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
c=d\label{equ:testb}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following warning message:

```
warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.1}) has b
een already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.28 \end{document}
                   pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
(name{equation.0.1a}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.28 \end{document}
                   ] (./a.aux) )
```

The problem is here:

```
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}
```

Using `\counterwithin` *after* `cleveref` produces a bad interaction with `hyperref`+`cleveref` (if one comments out the line loading `cleveref`, the problem disappears). The solution is to move the line `\counterwithin` *before* loading `cleveref`:

```
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
```

Comment: You are the best.  I would have never figured out this MWE to duplicate the error.

Comment: I came across similar warnings and had to put my AMSmath `\numberwithin{}` commands *after* `\hyperref{}`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the problem is with counters. If we set the equation counter manually, then it results in such type of problems. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

   \begin{equation}
      \mbox{Equation is given number but nonumber restores the value of equation counter.}\nonumber
   \end{equation}

   \begin{equation}
      \mbox{This equation is assigned the same number as the previous one because counter was reset.} 
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here we get the warning. But If we use starred version of equation i.e. `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`instead `\nonumber` as following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

   \begin{equation*}
      \mbox{Equation is not given any number.}
   \end{equation*}

   \begin{equation}
      \mbox{This equation is assigned unused number.} 
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and there is no warning. Same happens for the MWE provided by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina), subequation - counter being reset on section change. If we use `align` environment with `/nonumber`, then this problem does not occur. The reason being `/nonumber` is handled in a different way.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I traced the problem down. Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The problem arises when you use `amsmath` and `hyperref` packages, use the `\tag` command inside an `equation` environment, **and** use another `equation` environment later.

To avoid this problem, change the `equation` environment where you use `\tag` to `gather`. (No need to change `equation` environments where you don't use `\tag`.)

Comment: it's really bad to use successive `equation` environments with no intervening text.  i wasn't aware of the problem with `hyperref`, but will make a note to document it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton there is something similar if you instead use `\notag` inside `equation`, that should of course be altered to no `\notag` and using `equation*`. Thst one have stumped me on a few manuscript edits. Might note that one too

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is what helped in my case!