# Counting equations with two parallel counters

Tags: equations, numbering

First of all, a bit of introduction in order to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/252737): when I write a test/exams I like to keep text and solution together. Now, both the main text and the solution can have equations; I'd like that the equation numbering of the main text could be kept constant, both in the formulation-only document and the full one (formulation  with the solution).

I am able to do it for figures (I use `newfloat` to define a `solfigure` environment which has labels like **Figure S1** and so on), but I am at a loss thinking something similar with equation.

I prepared this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\ifsolution
\solutiontrue
\NewEnviron{solution}{\ifsolution\color{red}\expandafter\BODY\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    2x=4
    \label{eq:one}
\end{equation}

\begin{solution}
    \begin{equation}
        x=2
        \label{eq:solone}
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{equation}
    3x=6
    \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

With `\solutiontfalse` I have equation (1), (2); with `\solutiontrue` I have (1), (2), (3); I'd like to have (1), (S1), (2)... and so on, so that the equation for (2) is the same one both in the formulation and the formulation+solution document.

Extra point for having the tag in red, too.

With `\solutionfalse`:

[image: output for the formulation]

With `\solutiontrue`:

[image: output for the formulation + solution]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393778/displaying-counter-value-from-equation-tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just play with counters?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\ifsolution
\solutiontrue
\newcounter{fakeequation}
\newcounter{fakeeqtmp}
\NewEnviron{solution}{\setcounter{fakeeqtmp}{\value{equation}}\setcounter{equation}{\value{fakeequation}}%
    \renewcommand\theequation{S\arabic{equation}}\ifsolution\color{red}\expandafter\BODY\fi%
    \setcounter{fakeequation}{\value{equation}}\setcounter{equation}{\value{fakeeqtmp}}\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    2x=4
    \label{eq:one}
\end{equation}

\begin{solution}
    \begin{equation}
        x=2
        \label{eq:solone}
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{equation}
    3x=6
    \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}

\begin{solution}
    \begin{equation}
        x = 2
        \label{eq:soltwo}
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Explanation

I defined two extra counters `fakeequation` and `fakeeqtmp`.

At the start of the `solution` environment I stashed the value of `equation` into `fakeeqtmp` and loaded the value of `fakeequation` into `equation`. This is reversed at the end of the environment. So that inside the `solution` environment the counter being used is really the `fakeequation` counter, just addressed as `equation`.

I also included some code to format `\theequation` so that the equation labels look different inside and outside of the solution environments, included the capital "S" that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, +1, this will work. I will wait a bit to see if more solutions appear!

Comment: I like this solution for its simplicity --- and that it will probably work also with other math environments like `align` and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use `\tag` with `\ref`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifsolution
\solutiontrue
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}{%
  \ifsolution\color{red}#1\fi
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    2x=4
    \label{eq:one}
\end{equation}

\begin{solution}
    \begin{equation}
        x=2
        \tag{S\ref{eq:one}}
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{equation}
    3x=6
    \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Presumably both the question and the solution will sometimes have multiple equations, and they may not necessarily appear in the same order in the questions and the solutions, so using parallel counters is not an ideal solution. A better idea, as @egreg suggests, is to use `\ref{...}` to label the equations combined with the `\tag{..}` command.

To make this automatic you need to change the behaviour of the `equation` environment inside a `solution` environment. The code below redefines the `equation` environment inside a `solution` environment so that it is really an `equation*` environment (i.e. it has no equation number), and then the equation number is added using a `\tag` command. As well, a reference to the equation in the solution is added automatically. 
To make this work, inside a `solution` environment the `equation` environment **requires** an extra argument, which is the label of the equation from the questions.

With this in place, the code:

```
\begin{equation}
    2x=4
    \label{eq:one}
\end{equation}

\begin{solution}
  \begin{equation}{eq:one}% must give the ref to the question eq.
        x=2
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{equation}
    3x=6
    \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}

Equations \ref{eq:one}, \ref{eq:onesol} and \ref{eq:two}.
```

produces:

[image]

Notice that the label for the equation in the solutions is the same as the label for the corresponding equation in the question with `sol` appended.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifsolution
\solutiontrue

\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}{
  \ifsolution\color{red}
    % redefine the equation* environment
    \RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{m +b}{
      \begin{equation*}##2\tag{S\ref{##1}}
      \xdef\@currentlabel{S\noexpand\ref{##1}}% attach an S to the equation label
      \label{##1sol}% add the label
    }{\end{equation*}}
    #1
  \fi
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    2x=4
    \label{eq:one}
\end{equation}

\begin{solution}
  \begin{equation}{eq:one}
        x=2
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{equation}
    3x=6
    \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}

Equations \ref{eq:one}, \ref{eq:onesol} and \ref{eq:two}.
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used the `\NewDocumentEnvironment` command from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package, together with the `+b` option (which makes the body of the environment equal to `#1`...and with the `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` command above the body becomes `#2`, since `#1` is the equation label), instead of the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package.

One side effect of this is that you cannot have a labelled equation in the solutions unless it corresponds to an equation in the questions. With a little more effort it is possible to support this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am copying what I am using myself. It is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290019/194703) (at least I used it as a starting point). (At the very least I wanted to honorably mention this post. ;-) It does not precisely yield the output you want, but for a reason. Over the time I found that I want the thing work with `hyperref` and `cleveref` (so [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126365/194703) is relevant), and wanted to be able to move the solutions to separate locations, such as the end of the chapter. This is what I got.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\newtheoremstyle{exercise}% name
  {6pt}%      Space above
  {6pt}%      Space below
  {}%         Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries\boldmath}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}%     Space after thm head: " " = qnormal interword space;
        %       \newline = linebreak
  {\bignumber{#2} : #3}%         Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{exercise}

\newtheorem{Problem}{Problem}

\newtheoremstyle{solution}% name
  {3pt}%      Space above
  {3pt}%      Space below
  {\small}%         Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries\boldmath}% Thm head font
  {:}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {.3em}%     Space after thm head: " " = qnormal interword space;
        %       \newline = linebreak
  {Solution for exercise #3}%         Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{solution}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@theequation\theequation
\AtBeginEnvironment{Problem}{\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}%
\setcounter{equation}{\value{solequationstore}}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{P\latex@theequation}%
\renewcommand{\theHequation}{P\latex@theequation}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}%
\setcounter{equation}{\value{solequationstore}}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\latex@theequation}%
\renewcommand{\theHequation}{S\latex@theequation}}
\AtEndEnvironment{Problem}{%
\setcounter{solequationstore}{\value{equation}}%
\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{solution}{%
\setcounter{solequationstore}{\value{equation}}%
\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}%
}
\makeatother

\NewEnviron{Solution}[1][]{%
\ifkeepsol
\begin{solution}[#1]~%
\BODY
\end{solution}%
\fi
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newif\ifkeepsol
\keepsoltrue

\crefname{Problem}{problem}{problems}
\Crefname{Problem}{Problem}{Problems}
\newcounter{equationstore}
\newcounter{solequationstore}

\crefname{solution}{solution}{solutions}
\Crefname{solution}{Solution}{Solutions}


\begin{document}
\keepsolfalse\keepsoltrue
\begin{equation}
    2x=4
    \label{eq:one}
\end{equation}

\begin{Solution}[\ref{eq:one}]
    \begin{equation}
        x=2
        \label{eq:solone}
    \end{equation}
\end{Solution}

\begin{equation}
    3x=6
    \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}

\begin{Solution}[\ref{eq:two}]
    \begin{equation}
        x=2
        \label{eq:soltwo}
    \end{equation}
\end{Solution}

\begin{equation}
    3x=9
    \label{eq:three}
\end{equation}

\begin{Solution}[\ref{eq:three}]
    \begin{equation}
        x=3
        \label{eq:solthree}
    \end{equation}
\end{Solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]